# Circumscribed circle of a triangle in 2D

Tags: python, geometry

I've been struggling with this : how to get the center and radius of the circumscribed circle of a triangle (in 2D) ?
What I have done so far :

[I used the 1.5 linear system that is easily computable, however my implementation does not work at all...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFs3m.jpg)

My code (in python, using numpy for convenience):

```
def cercle_circonscrit(T):
   A = np.array([[x3-x1,y3-y1],[x3-x2,y3-y2]])
   Y = np.array([(x3**2 + y3**2 - x1**2 - y1**2),(x3**2+y3**2 - x2**2-y2**2)])
   if np.linalg.det(A) == 0:
       return False
   Ainv = np.linalg.inv(A)
   X = 0.5*np.dot(Ainv,Y)
   x,y = X[0],X[1]
   r = sqrt((x-x1)**2+(y-y1)**2)
   return (x,y),r
```

So far this returns inexplicable results... however I did not try to prove the above formula, which might be false...
Thanks

Comment: Where are the variables x1, x2, x3, etc coming from? They should be parameters of the function or extracted from a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to get (x1, y1), etc as parameters of the function.

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

def cercle_circonscrit(T):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) = T
    A = np.array([[x3-x1,y3-y1],[x3-x2,y3-y2]])
    Y = np.array([(x3**2 + y3**2 - x1**2 - y1**2),(x3**2+y3**2 - x2**2-y2**2)])
    if np.linalg.det(A) == 0:
        return False
    Ainv = np.linalg.inv(A)
    X = 0.5*np.dot(Ainv,Y)
    x,y = X[0],X[1]
    r = sqrt((x-x1)**2+(y-y1)**2)
    return (x,y),r

T = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))
cercle_circonscrit(T)
#--> ((0.5, 0.5), 0.7071067811865476)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did put them in my code (I made a mistake copypasting the code here, and I guess I also made a mistake when actually getting x1,y1 etc in my code since your code works perfectly).